# converting objects to datetime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having a problem converting objects that are dates into actual dates.

I'm reading in values from a datatable, and sending them to a JavaScriptSerializer so I can use the values in an open source calendar called fullCalendar.

The problem is, the feed from the JavaScriptSerializer contains dates and a boolean value.

My code looks like this:

```
        Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    For Each dr2 As DataRow In table.Rows
        row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
            If TypeOf (dr2(col)) Is DateTime Then
                dr2(col) = Convert.ToDateTime(dr2(col))
            End If
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr2(col))
        Next
        rows.Add(row)
    Next

    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim jsonEvents As String = serializer.Serialize(rows)
    Return jsonEvents
```

It runs without any errors, and all the values look good EXCEPT the date values.  They look strange like this:  "\ /Date(1313409600000)\ /".  They look like regular dates in the database, so I'm not sure whats going on here.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Javascript dates are stored internally as unix-style timestamps, in milliseconds since Jan 1/1970. `1313409600000` corresponds to Aug 15/2011.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that.  Maybe the issue is with the "\ /" characters placed in there...which I am not sure how they got there. -thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or above and the columns are `DATETIME` type, you should be able to do this:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = dr.Field(Of DateTime)("DateColumn")
```

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same date format.  Here is what it looks like now:`code`                If TypeOf (dr2(col)) Is DateTime Then
                    'Debug.Write("boolean object found: " & dr2(col))
                    'dr2(col) = Convert.ToDateTime(dr2(col))
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr2.Field(Of DateTime)(col))

                Else
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr2(col))

                End If`code`